# Batch: Open first folder in directory

Tags: batch-file, directory

Is there a way to open the first folder in a directory without knowing it's name?

If Command Prompt says

```
C://Users/Me/Desktop/Folder1
```

Imagine Folder2 is inside Folder1. I could easily just type:

```
cd Folder2
```

But Is there a way to do it if I didn't know it was called Folder2?

For example:

```
cd[0]
```

Do the folders have an index?

Help would be appreciated.

Tell me if I need to clarify the question.

Comment: Not really understanding what you mean by open?  Would help if you gave a brief explanation of what you are trying to do.

Comment: I have edited it, it is clearer now.

Comment: You confused me with open.  You are trying to change to a directory without knowing what directory to change to.  So if there are multiple folders in the directory you want to do a change directory to the first one.

Comment: Yes, that is right.

Comment: You want to run this command from the cmd prompt?

Comment: What do you consider as the *first* folder? do you think of a certain sort order (alphabetically, alphanumerically)? or do you not care?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This batch file will do change to the first directory in the current directory (or none, if there aren't any).

```
@echo off
for /d %%a in (*) do cd "%%~a"&&exit /b
```

There is no such thing as a folder index in Batch.

Comment: The "&&exit /b" didn't work, but I took it off and it worked well. Thanks!

Comment: @ZekeYoung, `exit /B` leaves the batch script, so it won't work if you try it in command prompt as it is terminated; one `&` symbol is enough, actually...